# What does "at least ordinal" mean?

Tags: measurement

When the assumptions of a statistical test state that "the measurement scale should be at least ordinal", what does that mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It refers to the [level of measurement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_of_measurement) of the variable you want to test. It means that that variable cannot be nominal.